# Resolving internal image paths?

Tags: media

Inside my template.php I am populating a custom variable to be used inside my **views-view-unformatted--latest_stories.tpl.php**

The image data associated with the content type has the structure:

```
[field_photos] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [fid] => 4
                        [uid] => 1
                        [filename] => DSCF2639_0.jpg
                        [uri] => public://story/photos/DSCF2639_0.jpg
                        [filemime] => image/jpeg
                        [filesize] => 129245
                        [status] => 1
                        [timestamp] => 1397504538
                        [alt] => 
                        [title] => 
                        [width] => 800
                        [height] => 600
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [fid] => 5
                        [uid] => 1
                        [filename] => DSCF2657.jpg
                        [uri] => public://story/photos/DSCF2657.jpg
                        [filemime] => image/jpeg
                        [filesize] => 89144
                        [status] => 1
                        [timestamp] => 1397504538
                        [alt] => 
                        [title] => 
                        [width] => 800
                        [height] => 600
                    )

            )

    )
```

How do I translate the path to a URI which a browser will be able to resolve?

Do I simply strip the public://

What if I move my files to AWS at a later date? Is there a function in drupal API that will handle this for me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the handy [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function:

> Creates a web-accessible URL for a stream to an external or local file.

Comment: I just stumbled across: image_style_url

I am most concerned about switching to AWS in the future and seeing as this uses stream wrappers I am hoping that handles this for me??

Comment: You wouldn't use `image_style_url()` unless you wanted to create the path to a derivative image (not the original), based on the original's URI. To get the URL for a specific file by URI, `file_create_url()` is the one. If the URI changes to `s3://foo.jpg` at some point, Drupal (well, actually PHP) will find an appropriate handler for the given protocol, and invoke the appropriate methods on it. So it's as reusable as you can get really

Comment: image_style_url() ends up calling file_create_url().  In addition to handling the stream wrappers, file_create_url() invokes hook_file_url_alter(), which is how the CDN module alters paths to point to whatever CDN you have defined.

Comment: @MPD It's great when you need the path to an image styles (which I don't think the OP does looking at the question). Doesn't work for originals or non-image files though

Comment: In  this case I think the image style option would work better as I am showing these images in a VIEW and want the image size to remain consistent, but both are handy to know.